# Can't read property from select value binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a select, and am trying to show a property when the select is changed (when a donation type is selected, I'd like to show a more lengthy description of the donation type).  Unfortunately, it's not working; I can't see to access the properties of the view model's selectedDonation property.

I have [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xUn9N/) that should help illustrate what I'm trying to do.  This is my first actual attempt at incorporating knockout.js into a project, so please excuse beginner mistakes.

My select looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableDonationTypes, optionsCaption: 'Please select...', value: selectedDonation.donationType, optionsText: 'label'"></select>
```

I'm trying to show the description here, but the ternary expression always evaluates to false.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedDonation() ? selectedDonation().donationType().description : 'No type selected'"></span>
```

If I use selectedDonation instead of selectedDonation() as the test, the expression evaluates to true, but I still can't find a way to access the selected donation type's description.

My viewmodel and object:

```
function Donation(donationType, donationAmount) {
    var self = this;
    self.donationAmount = donationAmount;
    self.donationType = ko.observable(donationType);

    self.formattedAmount = ko.computed(function () {
        var amount = self.donationAmount;
        return amount ? "$" + amount.toFixed(2) : "None";
    });
}

function DonationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableDonationTypes = [{
        label: "Donation 1",
        description: "This is donation number 1."
    }, {
        label: "Donation 2",
        description: "This is donation number 2."
    }];

    self.selectedDonation = ko.observable();

    self.donations = ko.observableArray([
    new Donation(self.availableDonationTypes[0], 50),
    new Donation(self.availableDonationTypes[1], 75)]);

    self.totalDonation = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.donations().length; i++)
        total += self.donations()[i].donationAmount;
        return total;
    });

    self.addDonation = function (form) {
        self.donations.push(new Donation(self.selectedDonation.donationType, parseInt(self.selectedDonation.donationAmount)));
    }
    self.removeDonation = function (donation) {
        self.donations.remove(donation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're problem is that `selectedDonation` starts out as nothing. You can't bind the `value` of the dropdown to the `dontationType` property of nothing: it doesn't such a property. `selectedDonation` needs to be a `donation` object.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that fixes the first binding, but if you select the caption it will break, since doing so sets the `value` to null, which doesn't have a `description` property: http://jsfiddle.net/xUn9N/1/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  However, looking at your jsFiddle, the changes that were made break the functionality when adding a donation.  Note how a row is added without any displayed values (other than a remove link).

Comment: Yeah, forgot some parens, here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xUn9N/2/

Comment: *blink* I don't even... Have been banging my head against this wall so hard, and you just casually answered it.  In comments.  I did address the "select the caption it will break" issue, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xUn9N/3/.  Seriously, thank you, and please consider rephrasing your answer as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that `selectedDonation` starts out as nothing. You can't bind the value of the dropdown to the `dontationTypee property of nothing: it doesn't have such a property.`selectedDonation`needs to be a`Donation` object.

Here is the final fiddle using that method: http://jsfiddle.net/xUn9N/3/